# How can I define variables that can be accessed from different files using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, nightwatch.js

I am automating e2e scenarios using Cucumber, Nightwatch / node.js and javaScript.

I want to define variables than can be accessed from different .js files. Currently there are some variables defined in globals/globals.js file in the following format:

```
module.exports = {
    testVar: "testVariableDefinition",
}
```

Once defined I am accessing them through:

```
var test = this.api.globals.testVar;
```

So this means that I want to define other variables in a file different than globals.js and access them later. The reason behind this is that I cannot define all variables in one file, it is a little bit messy.

Comment: Inside the same directory as your `globals.js`, just create another file say called, `globals_test.js`, and then you could just require it inside your `module.exports`,   `module.exports = { test: require("./globals_test") }`.. etc.  So this allows you to split your configs into small manageable files.

Comment: @Keith thank you very much! It works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've exported the variable, you could simply `import` or `require` it where you want to use.

```
// Assuming fileA.js and fileB.js are in the same directory
// fileA.js
module.exports = {
  testVar: "testVariableDefinition",
}

// fileB.js
const { testVar } = require('./fileA');
```